# How to add selectall using dropdownadapter on select2 v4

Tags: jquery, require, jquery-select2-4

I am not using require and trying to implement [this](http://jsbin.com/doxehivace/edit?html,js,output).

```
$(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
        ajax: {
            //url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
            url: "<?=BASE_URL ?>api/corporate-performance-dashboard/get-customers",
            dataType: 'json',
            type : 'POST',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                // scrolling can be used
                var dbData = [];
                //console.log(dbData);
                if(data.data != null){
                    for(i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
                        //console.log(data.data[i].GROUP_NAME);
                        dbData[i] = {id: data.data[i].GROUP_NAME_ID,full_name:data.data[i].GROUP_NAME, text:data.data[i].GROUP_NAME };
                        //console.log(dbData[i]);
                    }

                }
                //console.log(dbData);
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                //delete dbData[0];

                return {
                    results: dbData,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < dbData.length
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        multiple: true,
        tags: true,
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        templateResult: formatRepo,
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection,
        closeOnSelect: false,
        dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(
                  Utils.Decorate(
                    Dropdown,
                    AttachBody
                  ),
                  SelectAll
                ),
    }).on('change', function() {
        var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var $container = $('.js-example-tags-container');

        var $list = $('<ul>');
        $selected.each(function(k, v) {
            var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">x</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
            $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
                .off('click.select2-copy')
                .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
                    var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
                    $opt.attr('selected', false);
                    $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
            }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
            $list.append($li);
        });
        $container.html('').append($list);
    }).trigger('change');
```

My code seems to hang on `Utils`, it is not defined. I am using the `select2.full.js`.

**UPDATE**

How can I display the `select all` only when there is data?

```js
var Utils=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/utils');
var Dropdown=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/dropdown');
var AttachBody=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/dropdown/attachBody');

function formatRepo (repo) {
       if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

       var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
         "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'></div>" +
         "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
           "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

       if (repo.description) {
         markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";
       }

       markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
         //"<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + repo.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
         //"<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + repo.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
        // "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + repo.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
       "</div>" +
       "</div></div>";

       return markup;
  }

 function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
 }

 function formatResult (result) {

  if (result.loading) return "Searching...";
 }

 function SelectAll() { }

 SelectAll.prototype.render = function (decorated) {
  var $rendered = decorated.call(this);
       var self = this;

       var $selectAll = $(
         '<button type="button">Select All</button>'
       );

       $rendered.find('.select2-dropdown').prepend($selectAll);

       $selectAll.on('click', function (e) {
         var $results = $rendered.find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]');
         
         // Get all results that aren't selected
         $results.each(function () {
    var $result = $(this);
           
    // Get the data object for it
            var data = $result.data('data');
           
            // Trigger the select event
            self.trigger('select', {
              data: data
           });
         });
         
   self.trigger('close');
  });
      
  return $rendered;
 };
     
 $(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
   url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
        // url: "../../api/corporate-performance-dashboard/get-customers",
         dataType: 'json',
         type : 'POST',
         delay: 250,
         data: function (params) {
    return {
              q: params.term, // search term
              page: params.page
    };
         },
         processResults: function (data, params) {
    // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
    // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
    // scrolling can be used

    params.page = params.page || 1;
    //delete dbData[0];
              
              var jsonD = [{"error":false,"message":"","data":[{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"16323","GROUP_NAME":"AARHUS UNITED UK LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"44276","GROUP_NAME":"AMNESTY INTERNATIONAL UNITED KINGDOM_950138123"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40612","GROUP_NAME":"BAIN & COMPANY INC. UNITED KINGDOM_925001385"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3026","GROUP_NAME":"BECKMAN COULTER UNITED KINGDOM LTD_900028226"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40989","GROUP_NAME":"BOEING  UNITED KINGDOM LIMITED_925001540"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"43804","GROUP_NAME":"CONTITECH UNITED KINGDOM_925002897"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40454","GROUP_NAME":"CPM UNITED KINGDON LIMITED_925001355"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2316","GROUP_NAME":"CSM (UNITED KINGDOM) LTD_925000567"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2310","GROUP_NAME":"CUNNINGHAM LINDSEY UNITED KINGDOM_900002099"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"33735","GROUP_NAME":"EMBASSEY OF THE UNITED ARAB EMIRATES (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3132","GROUP_NAME":"EUROMEDIC UNITED KINGDOM  LTD_911460356"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3379","GROUP_NAME":"MCKINSEY & CO INC. UNITED KINGDOM_925000105"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"13699","GROUP_NAME":"OXFORD UNITED FOOTBALL CLUB LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4584","GROUP_NAME":"PUMA UNITED KINGDOM LTD_950005472"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3267","GROUP_NAME":"ROYAL UNITED HOSPITAL BATH - CATALIST_900223059"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"1436","GROUP_NAME":"S. & L. UNITED STORAGE SYSTEMS LTD_950031834"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"17550","GROUP_NAME":"SER SOLUTIONS UNITED KINGDOM LTD (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"17630","GROUP_NAME":"SGS UNITED KINGDOM LTD_925000665"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"42205","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LIMITED_925002404"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40001","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LLP_911430196"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2549","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGENTS LTD_911430196"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2548","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED AGRI PRODUCTS  LIMITED - GPRS_900182496"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"13327","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED ARAB EMIRATES EMBASSY (OneNet Core)"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4461","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED BUSINESS MEDIA GROUP LTD_900155663"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3842","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED BUSINESS MEDIA PLC - GPRS_900155663"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"24535","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED CARPETS LTD_910766502"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"41498","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED CAST BAR (UK) LTD_950105891"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"43894","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DAIRY FARMERS LIMITED_925003162"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"723","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DAIRY FARMERS_910115981"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40800","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED DRUG PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY_925001555"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"113","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED LINCOLNSHIRE HOSPITALS CATALIST_900219353"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2547","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED RESPONSE - CATALIST_900254800"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"24366","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED STATES EMBASSY_911415962"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2546","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED THERAPEUTICS EUROPE LTD_911232907"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"112","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED UTILITIES GROUP PLC_925000155"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40803","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED UTILITY GROUP PLC - M2M_925000941"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3841","GROUP_NAME":"UNITED WELSH HOUSING ASSOC. - CATALIST_900275753"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"3176","GROUP_NAME":"UNITEDHEALTH UK LTD_911169045"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"4454","GROUP_NAME":"VANDERLANDE INDUSTRIES UNITED KINGDOM LT_911405044"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"687","GROUP_NAME":"WMF UNITED KINGDOM LIMITED_910383186"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"2506","GROUP_NAME":"WPS UNITED KINGDOM LTD_910465482"},{"GROUP_NAME_ID":"40186","GROUP_NAME":"YOKOGAWA UNITED KINGDOM LTD_950099226"}],"dbdataCount":null}];
console.log(data);
              var dbData = [];
           for(i=0;i<jsonD[0].data.length;i++){
            dbData[i] = {id: jsonD[0].data[i].GROUP_NAME_ID, full_name:jsonD[0].data[i].GROUP_NAME};
           }
              console.log(jsonD);
    
    return {
     results: dbData,
     pagination: {
      more: (params.page * 30) < dbData.length
     }
    };
         },
         cache: true
  },
  multiple: true,
  //tags: true,
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  templateResult: formatRepo,
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection,
  closeOnSelect: false,
  dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(
    Utils.Decorate(
           Dropdown,
           AttachBody
         ),
         SelectAll
       ),
 }).on('change', function() {
  //if($(this).text())
     var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
     var $container = $('.js-example-tags-container');

     var $list = $('<ul>');
     $selected.each(function(k, v) {
   var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">x</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
   $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
          .off('click.select2-copy')
          .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
             var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
     $opt.attr('selected', false);
             $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
         }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
        $list.append($li);
  });
     $container.html('').append($list);
 }).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="border-radius">
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
   <fieldset class="border-radius white-bg">
   <legend class="border-radius">Search Customer/s</legend>
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <select class="js-example-data-ajax" style="width:100%">
       
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <button id="search_customers" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    </div>
            <div class="js-example-tags-container">
       
      </div>
 
   </fieldset>
   
  </div>
  <!-- //.span6 -->

  <div class="col-md-6 ">
   <fieldset class="border-radius white-bg">
   <legend class="border-radius">Search Customer/s</legend>
    <div class="col-md-10">
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    </div>
              
              <div>display select in list here</div>
 
   </fieldset>
   
  </div>
  <!-- //.span6 -->
 </div>
 <!-- //.row-fluid -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use require to load components into local variables. If you insist not to use require, maybe you can try this out:

```
var Utils=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/utils');
var Dropdown=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/dropdown');
var AttachBody=$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/dropdown/attachBody');
```

UPDATE:
The simplest way is to set a listener to check if there has options inside the select tag, if not, add a style on that button let it `display:none`

Comment: You already got the answer, so you should create another question instead of updating the original one