# How to add Search feature in multiselect dropdown list at Select2

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to add Search feature in [Select2](https://select2.org) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918749/5043301). My Code is like below.

```
(function($) {  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function (event) {
        let element_id = event.target.id;
        // Check if select is already loaded
        if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
          var cellEle = $(this);

          // Populate select element
          cellEle.html(`<select multiple="multiple"></select>`);

          // Initialise select2
          let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
            matcher: function(params, data) {
              // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
              if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                return data;
              }
              // Skip if there is no 'children' property
              if (typeof data.children === 'undefined') {
                return null;
              }
              // `data.children` contains the actual options that we are matching against
              var filteredChildren = [];
              $.each(data.children, function (idx, child) {
                if (child.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
                  filteredChildren.push(child);
                }
              });
              // If we matched any of the timezone group's children, then set the matched children on the group
              // and return the group object
              if (filteredChildren.length) {
                var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
                modifiedData.children = filteredChildren;

                // You can return modified objects from here
                // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
                return modifiedData;
              }
              // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
              return null;
            },
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            allowClear: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 3,
            minimumResultsForSearch: 5,
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
              url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: function (params, page) {
                return {
                  action: 'get_data',
                  q: params,
                };
              },
              type: "post",
              processResults: function (data) {
                var options = [];
                if (data) {
                  $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                    options.push({ id: index, text: text });
                  });
                }
                return {
                  results: options
                };
              }
            }
          });
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

But I am not getting Search feature. I am getting output like below.

[image]

Comment: When using a multi-select dropdown Select2 does not display a separate search input, instead you type into the section where the selected options appear. There is not a single configuration option to display the search input for multi-select. If it's required then I suggest referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64260625/1620449) which uses the [dropdownAdapter](https://select2.org/advanced/default-adapters/dropdown) to add the search input for multi-select.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisC for your reply. How Search will work with multi-select dropdown Select2 if I use AJAX ? You'll get an idea from image I posted. If I type it is not working. Did you check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917204/select2-default-values-for-multiple-select-and-allowed-tags/37918749#37918749) ? Is it possible to Sort the values also ?

Comment: When using Ajax you would filter the data server-side. The search term can be passed in the Ajax request as detailed [here](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#request-parameters) from `params.term`, you then return only the relevant options in the response. For sorting you could return sorted results from server-side, or sort them in [processResults](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data) once they are retrieved.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisC. Did you check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917204/select2-default-values-for-multiple-select-and-allowed-tags/37918749#37918749) ? It is not using AJAX, that's why search is working here, right ?

Comment: @ChrisC. Is it possible to have Search on AJAX fetched values ?

Comment: Correct if you are not using Ajax then the search is just done locally in the browser, as per the example you linked. If you are using Ajax then you could be fetching thousands of values, handling the filter/search on the server prevents you from returning all of these to the browser in one go. If you don't have too many values you could retrieve the values first in a separate Ajax request, then initialise select2 without Ajax just passing in the values to get local search/filtering.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisC. Could you please show me some sample code if I retrieve the values first in a separate Ajax request, then initialize select2 without Ajax just passing in the values to get local search/filtering ? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240876/discussion-between-chris-c-and-abu-abu).